# For how long can the wind blow unabated on a "trade wind route"?

Tags: meteorology, wind, weather-forecasting

Take a specific point at sea level (less than 100 meters above it) on a "trade wind" oceanic route. For example, somewhere on Labrador-Ireland route, at roughly 50 degrees of latitude north. Let's say, early July to late October. Supposedly, I should find "nearly constant" winds blowing roughly west to east there. My question is about that "nearly":

**For how many *consecutive* days should I expect the wind to blow unabated (let's say, at a minimum of 4 knots) at that point?** With "blow unabated", I mean "blow without a single second of interruption". If it matters at all, note that I am interested only in wind force, not direction: if the wind were to turn 180 degrees but still kept blowing at 4 knots or stronger, I'd still consider it unabated.

This is probably a very naive question, and despite my best efforts may be missing crucial details. In general, any pointer to information that helped me understand these "gaps in average wind circulation" would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The best I can do is point you at doing some research into what they call the "Viking route" in transatlantic sailing. That should give you some indication of how steady those northern trade winds are.